# Is the Catholic Church actively preparing for the contact with a highly advanced sentient alien species?

Tags: catholicism, extra-terrestrial-life

> According to constitutional and public interest lawyer and educator Daniel Sheehan, the Catholic Church is actively preparing for the discovery of and contact with a highly advanced sentient alien species. He spoke today at Contact in the Desert 2015, a landmark UFO conference in Joshua Tree in Southern California, where he described what will be a historic papal encyclical decree calling for nothing less than the disassembly of the power structures that are destroying our civilization and preventing us from joining an enlightened galactic partnership.
>   [Pope Francis and Catholic Church Are Preparing For Alien Contact - The Ghost Diaries](http://theghostdiaries.com/on-june-5th-pope-francis-will-announce-the-catholic-church-is-preparing-for-alien-contact/)

Is the Catholic Church really actively preparing for the discovery of and contact with a highly advanced sentient alien species? What is the evidence that suggests this?

Comment: Literally the only sources making this claim are website dedicated to paranormal and extraterrestrial conspiracies. Do you have any credible news sources to cite from?

Comment: Honestly, I don't know what the Catholic Church would be able to do considering we don't know what kind of species it would be. I would be surprised if the Church was able to take the ideas C.S. Lewis presented in his "Religion and Rocketry" and Space trilogy much further without actual contact. Lewis does have a good following within the Church and I am sure some believe Lewis' points worth exploring. If you want to know what those are, "religion and rocketry" is a very short essay that sums up most ideas in the book trilogy.

Comment: well, Jesus is from another world. So yes, every member is preparing to meet Him.

Comment: Also, I'm pretty sure it is well known that Pope Francis is currently working on an encyclical about Climate Change and the environment. He's probably not doing two at once.

Comment: These kinds of questions can be asked on [skeptics.se].

Comment: The Catholic expert on this subject is Alain Kerizo. Read his "[Who's Behind the UFO Phenomenon](http://www.angelusonline.org/index.php?section=articles&subsection=print_article&article_id=2102)". See also: Marie I. George's [_The Thomist_](http://www.thomist.org/jourl/explore.htm) article "[Aquinas on Intelligent Extra-Terrestrial Life](http://www.thomist.org/jourl/2001/April/2001%20Apr%20A%20George%20web.htm)."

Comment: Regarding the encyclical just released, which is about climate change. http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2015/05/29/pope-francis-climate-change-encyclical-laudato-si_n_7471288.html

Answer (score 9):

There is ***NO EVIDENCE WHATSOEVER*** that such a thing is true.

The Pope is, indeed, working on an encyclical, scheduled for release probably June 2015; but its subject is the environment (see for example [this PDF](http://www.usccb.org/issues-and-action/human-life-and-dignity/environment/environmental-justice-program/upload/Global-Climate-Change-Backgrounder-2015-02.pdf) on the website of the U.S. Council of Catholic Bishops).

The Catholic Church has no stand on the actual existence of life outside of Earth; it does not state either that such a thing cannot be, nor that it is the case.

That being true, the Church—which has no knowledge of any "highly advanced sentient alien species—is in no position to make statements on such a possible entity.

Comment: [What's the Catholic position on the existence of extra-terrestrial life?](http://www.catholic.com/quickquestions/whats-the-catholic-position-on-the-existence-of-extra-terrestrial-life)

Answer (score 0):

Given the focus of the Catholic Church on the gospel of Jesus Christ, I think it is highly unlikely that the Catholic Church is preparing for alien contact. It is more likely that the speaker is trying to improve his credibility by associating himself with a trusted organization.

Establishing a "galactic partnership" does not line up with the mission of the Catholic Church (or any Christian church) unless it involves establishing a peaceful relationship built on the gospel of Jesus Christ – which is, as stated in the scriptures, "for the salvation of every creature."

Avoiding entirely the topic of whether or not intelligent life exists nearby in our universe – or whether or not it would attempt to make contact – there would be no reason for a church that preaches Christ to seek "enlightenment" from an extraterrestrial species. As stated by Peter in the New Testament (John 6:68), which the Catholic Church regards as scripture, "Lord, to whom shall we go? thou hast the words of eternal life."

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Your answer here is more of a discussion forum style type post. On this site, it's a pretty strict question and answer framework. But it's not really your fault; It's kind of a dumb question.

Comment: OK, I made my thesis more clear: that it's "highly unlikely" that the Catholic Church is preparing for alien contact. Agreed that it's kind of a wacky question. :)

Comment: This answer would be acceptable if you could add references showing that this is a common understanding, and who teaches/believes it. On this site, we're not looking for personal interpretation, but rather focusing on what various Christian groups teach.  See [How we are different than other sites?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/) and [What makes a good supported answer?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/692/)